# i'm working on the autocomplete for displaying the city name and also the city id in hidden,

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Im getting the response as:

```
0: {id: "190", name: "Elurupadu"}
1: {id: "1230", name: "Sendhwa"}
2: {id: "1262", name: "Multai"}
3: {id: "1480", name: "Kherwara"}
4: {id: "2225", name: "Mandi"}
5: {id: "519", name: "Thamarassery"}
6: {id: "208", name: "Ayyampettai"}
7: {id: "5519", name: "Udaipur"}
8: {id: "26977", name: "Siddapura(Udupi)"}
9: {id: "1151", name: "Murthal"}
10: {id: "327", name: "Pillayarpatti"}
11: {id: "2022", name: "Siddapura"}
12: {id: "738", name: "Therthally"}
13: {id: "1112", name: "Chandigarh"}
14: {id: "2358", name: "Kadodra"} 
...............
```

I want to convert it as:

```
[ {id: "960",name: "Elurupadu"},
  {id: "1230",name: "Senhwa"},
  {id: "1262",name: "Multai"},
  ...
];
```

can any one help me for sorting out, im using javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: are you sure about the first given formatting? could it be a console view of an array of objects?

Comment: You should delete your question and restructure it before it gets more bad reviews. I accidentally did that a few times too. You should provide your input too! Not just the results your getting, after all it's your input we need to help edit ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
var dt=[];
dt.push({id: "190", name: "Elurupadu"})
dt.push({id: "1230", name: "Sendhwa"})
dt.push({id: "1262", name: "Multai"})
dt.push({id: "1480", name: "Kherwara"})
dt.push({id: "2225", name: "Mandi"})
dt.push({id: "519", name: "Thamarassery"})
dt.push({id: "208", name: "Ayyampettai"})
dt.push({id: "5519", name: "Udaipur"})
dt.push({id: "26977", name: "Siddapura(Udupi)"})
dt.push({id: "1151", name: "Murthal"})
dt.push({id: "327", name: "Pillayarpatti"})
dt.push({id: "2022", name: "Siddapura"})
dt.push({id: "738", name: "Therthally"})
dt.push({id: "1112", name: "Chandigarh"})
dt.push({id: "2358", name: "Kadodra"})

//convert
var result=JSON.stringify(dt);
console.log(result);
/*[{"id":"190","name":"Elurupadu"},{"id":"1230","name":"Sendhwa"},{"id":"1262","name":"Multai"},{"id":"1480","name":"Kherwara"},{"id":"2225","name":"Mandi"},{"id":"519","name":"Thamarassery"},{"id":"208","name":"Ayyampettai"},{"id":"5519","name":"Udaipur"},{"id":"26977","name":"Siddapura(Udupi)"},{"id":"1151","name":"Murthal"},{"id":"327","name":"Pillayarpatti"},{"id":"2022","name":"Siddapura"},{"id":"738","name":"Therthally"},{"id":"1112","name":"Chandigarh"},{"id":"2358","name":"Kadodra"}]
*/
```

Comment: hi tanq u .   but when iam stringifying it , it is displaying as  ex : [{"id":190,"name":Elurupadu"}....],  but id and name it should not be in string, only its value should be in string., please let me know any other way is there.

Comment: you can try this way

Comment: your  response is what you want

Comment: i didnt got you